# Unable to save BufferedImage to specified URL

Tags: java, swing, url, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am trying to store Image on remote location.

```
BufferedImage img;
img=ImageIO.read(file);
String url="http://localhost:8080/prashant Pic/j.jpg";
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",new File("/home/com/Documents/images/p.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",new File("http://localhost:8080/prashant Pic/j.jpg"));
```

It stores Images on local computer. But does not on localhost.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` isn't a file, it's a service.

Comment: Imagine if `localhost` was a remote host, live to the internet.  Would you be wanting people, with that code snippet, to be able to post their entire(1) porn collection to your site?  (1) Or any part of it - for that matter!

Comment: BTW - you might change `ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",new File("http://localhost:8080/prashant Pic/j.jpg"));` to `ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",new File(url));` for the same effect.  ;)  Also `String url="http://localhost:8080/prashant Pic/j.jpg";` would better be `String url="http://localhost:8080/prashant%20Pic/j.jpg";`

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to store images on a remote location. Instead of using `File`, use something like:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/prashant%20Pic/j.jpg");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// Do necessary setup of connection, like:
//  - setting the HTTP method (POST/PUT)
//  - setting authentication parameters?
// These depends on what kind of service you have running on localhost:8080

OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
try {
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", stream);
}
finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

Obviously, you also need a service running on localhost:8080 that accepts file upload via POST or PUT.